# Invoke controller from ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Do you know if I can invoke a controller from a ViewComponent in asp.net core?
I was trying something like this

```
public MyViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
         return (IViewComponentResult) new RedirectToActionResult
                        ("actionName", "controllerName", null);
    }

}
```

But I obviously get an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Have you tried to create your controller and call your action?

Comment: I already have the controller and the action I need to invoke. The problem is how to call it inside the viewcomponent

Comment: I mean that can't you create an object instance of your controller class inside your ViewComponent? If you can, you can call the action via that created object.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if I can invoke a controller from a ViewComponent in asp.net core? I was trying something like this `return (IViewComponentResult) new RedirectToActionResult("actionName", "controllerName", null);`

It does not make sense to do what you are trying to do.

A controller handles HTTP requests; a ViewComponent does not handle HTTP requests ([see this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#invoking-a-view-component-directly-from-a-controller)). In fact, it's more likely that you're going to call a ViewComponent from a Controller that call a Controller from a ViewComponent.

The `RedirectToActionResult` that you're trying to use will try to redirect an existing HTTP request from on URL to a different URL. Since a ViewComponent is not handling an HTTP request, there is nothing to redirect, and the `RedirectToActionResult` is not appropriate.

If you *really* want to call a Controller from a ViewComponent, then you have two options:

1. Inside your ViewComponent, create a instance of the Controller and directly call one of its Actions. This will be a little bit odd, because you will have to manually manage the Controllers context and dependencies.
2. Inside your ViewComponent, get an instance of an HttpClient, and use it to make an HTTP request to the Controller Action.

Comment: Can you kindly check this thread please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777025/how-to-download-the-coverted-doc-file-from-viewcomponent